# Limit user to only use a single command that I want to permit them to run

Tags: permissions, 22.04, security, users, ifconfig

I would like to create a user on Ubuntu 22.04 CLI to only be able to run ifconfig. That's it. No other commands, not even cd or ls, should be available to them to use for security reasons. They log in, view the private IP address of the machine, and log out.

Is there a way to limit a user in this way?

Comment: It is possible to run commands on `~/.bashrc`, maybe you could try adding `ifconfig && exit` at the end of it, and it would possibly work as "here is your IP address and now get the hell out of here!"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498667/how-to-limit-user-commands-in-linux

Comment: I would opt for another method: if that user has another system you could set up something like ssh to have it return the results of ifconfig. Or have your system mail the results of ifconfig on demand.

Comment: XY problem - why run `ifconfig`? What information do the users extract? Are the users local (what's my IP?) or remote (what's the IP of other node?). There are probably easier ways.

Comment: As you don't want the user to input anything, replace the shell of the user with a script that does only what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Building off of the [other answer here by petep](https://askubuntu.com/a/1429944/10616), there's a few things you might want to consider doing in this case in addition to just creating the user.

In default Ubuntu there is some pre-login SSH stuff that generates that MOTD giving you information about the system and what not.  In addition, you also need to have a home directory for the user that is ephemeral just in case something creates a file.

First, in order to disable the dynamic MOTD, you need to make revisions to `/etc/pam.d/sshd` as superuser and find these two lines:

```
session    optional    pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional    pam_motd.so noupdate
```

Comment them out by placing a `#` at the beginning of the lines and then saving the file.  This disables the dynamic MOTD giving system information out.

Now, we move to user creation.  We'll condense the steps made by petep into one smaller set of commands.  We will create the user, and then set the password.

```
sudo useradd --home=/tmp --shell /sbin/ifconfig user1
sudo passwd user1
```

Once this is done and you've rebooted the machine once (so PAM recognizes updates), then when this user SSH's they'll only be able to get the `ifconfig` output and then their connection will immediately terminate.

However, keep in mind that if you ever need this user to run anything *other* than `ifconfig` you will have a much more difficult time from a security perspective configuring what the user can and cannot run, as it's generally accepted that a given user will have access to 'most' of the standard `PATH` defined executables - if that isn't the case then you'd have to properly chroot the person in one directory with a smaller set of commands and that gets extremely tedious to modify and maintain long term.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your users shell to ifconfig command.
 The users password must be set though?
`sudo useradd user1`
`sudo passwd user1`
`sudo usermod --shell /sbin/ifconfig user1`

Comment: Do you mind if I build off of your answer?  There's some other stuff that needs to be done - properly setting home dir, properly disabling the MOTD that gives sytem info at SSH logins, etc.  That will give a more complete answer so that the user *only* gets the ifconfig output.  Note that this also requires `/sbin/ifconfig` to be installed, which is *not* the case in modern Ubuntu systems.

Comment: No, go right ahead. -Pete

Comment: thanks, I gave you credit in my answer and built off of it.  I did condense the useradd / usermod to a single line (yay for sysadmin!) but it's based off your answer, with some extra customization/flair from me with additional things OP might want to disable (dyamic MOTD about system info and stuff).

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking of **remote logins** (via ssh), you can utilize the [`ForceCommand` option in `sshd_config`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5#ForceCommand), which can be used to force the execution of a specific command ignoring any command from the client. In conjuction with `Match User`, this restriction can be limited to specific users.

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, add the following lines

```
Match User username
    ForceCommand ifconfig
```

This will ignore any command issued by user *username* and execute `ifconfig` instead.

Alternatively, instead of `ifconfig`, configure a small script that checks the provided command and echoes an error if it is not `ifconfig`.

Example:

```
Match User limiteduser
    ForceCommand /opt/custom/ssh/forcecommand.sh
```

Then `/opt/custom/ssh/forcecommand.sh` could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
# Check for allowed command

if [ -z "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" ]; then
  # User entered with no command - creating shell
  exec $SHELL -l 
else
  if [ "$COMMAND1" == 'ifconfig' ]; then
    # Allowed command
    exec ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}
  else
    echo "Rejected - you are not allowed to issue ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}"
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

If you want to limit **local logins**, you may want to take a look at [*lshell*](https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell), which is a shell coded in Python, that lets you restrict a user's environment to limited sets of commands and other things. I haven't tried it myself, but it looks like it was made for your requirement.

Setting the user's shell to *lshell* could limit both local and remote logins.